# JavaScript, How to quickly copy an array of objects but only with the value I need in that object

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, I have an array of objects

```
var arr = [];
var obj1 = {
name: apple,
color: red,
price: 2
};
var obj2 = {
name: pear,
color: green,
price: 5
};
arr.push(obj1);
arr.push(obj2);
```

so now my `arr` has two objects, what I want to achieve is, I want to copy this `arr`, but only the value for `name` and `price`. So my result should look like this:

```
arrCopy = [
{name: apple,
price: 2},
{name: pear,
price: 5}
]
```

Currently, I can only think of loop through the array, extract the value I want and store it into a new object, push this new object to the new array.

My question is, is there any other way to achieve this? like some method similar to the `slice` method?

Comment: Array.prototype.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this:

ES5

```
var out = arr.map(function (obj) {
 return { name: obj.name, price: obj.price }
});
```

ES6

```
var out = arr.map(obj => ({ name: obj.name, price: obj.price }));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e14bkfya/3/)**

Comment: And if they're writing in an environment that supports it, this can be shortened by using an arrow function for the callback: `arr.map(x => ({name: x.name, price: x.price}))`

Comment: or `arr.map(({name, price}) => ({name, price}))` (3 bytes shorter :p)

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out!